# Google App Engine Push Task - Using the DeferredTasks instead of a worker service warning

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, objectify

There is a warning about using `DeferredTask` in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks) that says:

> Warning: While the DeferredTask API is a convenient way to handle
>   serialization, you have to carefully control the serialization
>   compatibility of objects passed into payload methods. Careful control
>   is necessary because unprocessed objects remain in the task queue,
>   even after the application code is updated. Tasks based on outdated
>   application code will not deserialize properly when the task is
>   decoded with new revisions of the application.

I don't understand this. What does it mean "careful control"? Does anyone have an example of how one can write a poor `DefeferredTask`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java serialization follows certain rules that you need to be aware of. By default, any change to a Java class "breaks" serialization; objects serialized with the old class cannot be deserialized with the new class.

If you declare a `serialVersionUID` in your class (and don't change the value), then deserialization will be allowed even as you change the class. It will do what you normally expect if you're used to serializing to/from JSON and adding/removing fields to/from your classes. Ie, fields removed from classes will leave data ignored and new fields added will be have default values.

Some people hate Java serialization and some people love it. It's useful, and very convenient when working with the task queue. If you always declare a `serialVersionUID` you'll probably be fine... most mistakes will cause exceptions when you try to serialize data, and you'll figure those pretty quickly.

Comment: I see... hmm well in my deferred task I am just doing some datastore operations in it's `run()` method and that is all. Does this whole serialization thing even apply..?

Comment: Serialization applies to whatever data (fields) you have in your class. If you don't have any fields, it's easy! You should still declare a `serialVersionUID` in case you add fields in the future. And remember the package path and class name can't change (if you want to rename it, copy it and only delete the old version after you've drained the queues).

Comment: Ah ok. So then if I specify a `serialVersionUID` I should change its value with every new project version deployment?

Comment: I strongly strongly recommend reading up on the basics of Java serialization. No, you want to *never* change the value otherwise you won't be able to deserialize old tasks.

Comment: Shouldn't I update the value of `serialVersionUID` if I change the fields of the deferred task?

Comment: No. If you change the serialVersionUID, then serialized data with the old ID will not be able to be deserialized by the new class. At all.

If you change fields but keep the same id, then it will work according to some basic rules... fields that stay the same will be deserialized correctly. New fields will be initialized to default values. Deleted fields will just be ignored. If you're used to working with JSON it's basically the same.